# Celery delay().get() doesnt return when worker is running on Windows

Tags: celery

I setup basic celery example [myapp.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/app/myapp.py) of celery using redis as baker and backend.
When I run worker on Windows, running the delay().get() doesnt return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of specifying result backend when initialize the app, put it in app.conf.update code (https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/897#issuecomment-57350929) worked for me